# How to open USB drive in read-only/write protected mode in OSX, programmatically using objective C?

Tags: objective-c, macos, usb, mac-app-store

I'm trying to write a mac app to access USB. The USB can be written through app only and not in other means. I want to make sure,app is having exclusive write access to it. I tried to find some apis in disarbitration but all efforts are gone in vain.

Adding Further details ::
I'm not trying to make all USB ports as read-only. When I plugin USB drive to the system, it should ask for password. If authentication fails, then user can view the files but can't write to it.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking for. what did you try so far? Is it a specific USB device? Or all USB ports on the computer?

Comment: I tried to find any apis are there in Mac OSX IOKit to open the USB in readonly mode. I'm not trying to block USB ports,I'm trying to do it for USBdrive.
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/USBBook/USBIntro/USBIntro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000973